# How to use * (asterisk) in NuxtJs route?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

In a normal Vue (not Nuxt) project generated by vue-cli, using `*` in vue-router like this works:

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      component: About,
      children: [
        {
          path: "*",
          component: About
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

All these routes works:

- `/about`
- `/about/123`
- `/about/123/abc/123/abc`

Is there a way to do this in NuxtJs ? In Nuxt, routes are generated automatically from the files in `pages` folder. but `*` is an invalid character for file/folder name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Nuxt 3

In Nuxt 3 the pattern has changed, instead of using `_` as the filename you use `[var]`. This is then available as `route.params.var`:

The example from the documentation shows:

```
-| pages/
---| index.vue
---| users-[group]/
-----| [id].vue
```

In this case, the dynamic route param here is `route.params.id`. This would match the following:

```
/users-[group]/[id].vue
```

Of course, it's up to you to format the route in the way that makes the most sense for your use case.

## Nuxt 2

You use `_` to denote that it's a wildcard, like:

```
pages/about/_.vue
```

Will resolve `/about/*`, which is what I believe you're looking for

And if you want the dynamic directory structure:

```
pages/about/_/abc/_/abc.vue
```

Would resolve for `about/123/abc/123/abc` (but it doesn't make much sense)

Comment: thanks. it works . may i know how did you know this? i can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: @JacobGoh Sorry, I don't know. Nuxt documentation is terrible, I've just worked with Nuxt for awhile now.

Comment: @JacobGoh Found it in the documentation, [it's not super clear, but you can see an example here](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/custom-routes/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually asking this question because I am curious about how to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951479/infinite-dynamic-level-nesting-in-nuxt-js . I think ur method would solve the problem and you can answer it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy how to achieve this in Nuxt 3?

Comment: @devzakir Updated for Nuxt 3.

Comment: In Nuxt 3 the catchall syntax is `[...].vue`