# how to create dynamic and interchangeable nested routes in nuxt?

Tags: dynamic, routes, nested, nuxt.js

According to documentation, for dynamic routing we should nest folder with folder name _paramname, then nuxt automatically generate route for this dynamic subfolder. I can't understand, how to arrange folder structure, if routes should be dynamic AND interchangeable. For example: I have five or more types of filters, each type contains five to twenty possible variants. Ideally, when user choose some filter, I would like to generate routes like:

```
/mainfolder/filtertype(n)option/filtertype(n)option/
```

where dynamic 'filtertype(n)option' segments are interchangeable.

If I create folder structure like this:

```
-mainfolder
--_filtertype1
  --_filtertype2
```

etc, nuxt creates routes in hard order, where no ways to change filtertype segments by each other. I suppose that I should create some structure, where there are any possible combination of nested routes. But it seams not scalable, messy and unclear. Like this:

```
-mainfolder
--_filtertype1
  --_filtertype2
    --_fiiltertype3
  --_filtertype3
    --_filtertype2
    
--filtertype2
  --_filtertype1
    --_filtertype3
  --_filtertype3
    --_filtertype1
```

etc.
Are there any standard resolves of this task?

Comment: Maybe this can help?
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes

If the req. is dynamic AND interchangeable, then there seems to be option to customize the logic using the @nuxtjs/router module

Comment: May be it will help you
[How to use * (asterisk) in NuxtJs route?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49952457/6433967)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood the whole question but I know that Nuxt 3 (with Vue3) will come with Vue Router 4 and will allow for interpolated names in the pages directory.

So, rather than having `pages/_slug.vue`, it will be `pages/[slug].vue`, and therefore you could interpolate it to your wishes. Source: https://nuxtjs.slides.com/atinux/state-of-nuxt-2020#/5/6/6

Unfortunately, Nuxt3 will probably come in Q2 2021, so there is still some time to go.

Until then, I'm afraid that you need to do it manually, the old fashioned way.